# How do I submit my Facebook graph api action for approval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a mobile phone app, supporting web site and a Facebook account
When certain actions are taken on my phone app I interact with my web server. My web server then posts some info to a page on MY Facebook account.

I chose to use the graph api to achieve the posts to my Facebook page but I can see no way of complying with Facebooks requirements for submission.

When I try to submit facebook states the following

> No Aggregations created for this Action Type. Please create a
>   completed Aggregation populated with sample data before submitting for
>   review.

Firstly I have no idea what an aggregation is?

Then the docs state

> Review your Action Type before submitting for approval. Make sure your
>   definition is complete and your app is testable end-to-end for
>   publishing actions of this Action Type

Which makes sense but how do I get my mobile app to Facebook staff so they can test?

I should add that all works fine in development mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create an action via the [Facebook Open Graph Beta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/), you should first look into the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/). There you will find all information on actions, objects and aggregations you can generate on the timeline.
Further you will have to go to the subsection *Open Graph* of your App Settings:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/opengraph and create your aggregations populated with sample data.

If you want to make a simple post though, then use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) and POST a [Post object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) to the feed connection of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user). There are a lot of examples and tutorials on the web and a lot of questions on that matter here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like what I really need to do is just a post to a page on my own account using the graph api. I got very confused about the various api options and you have cleared that up for me. But now my question becomes how do I get an access token to programatically post to my own page?

Comment: I think a good point to start is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ Look under **App Login** and **Page Login**. You will need to grant two permissions, the _publish_stream_ and the _manage_pages_ permission.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that and granted the permissions using a url in my browser but still no wiser on how to get the token. The app login docs don't make that clear or I don't understand properly :)

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this as a separate question

Comment: Yes, that would be wise : ] And also a good idea would be if you post the code you already tried.

Comment: thank you for your help - I have posted a new question here http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8527125/where-do-i-get-an-access-token-from-to-post-to-my-facebook-page-using-fbgraph-ge